# resposta do javascript não aparece na pagina, só no console

Tags: php, javascript, api, codeigniter

Boa noite,

Estou utilizando codeigniter, estou implementando a api do pagseguro, e estou utilizando um javascript pra setar o id da sessão e chamar os métodos de pagamentos, até agora está tudo funcionando, só que em uma função **listarMeiosPag()** no javascript, ele traz o resultado apenas em console.log, se mando ele mostrar o resultado em uma div da pagina, ele simplesmente não mostra, nem alert exibe tb, mas se coloco o alert direto no script da pagina ele exibe, não sei como resolver isso, se algúem puder me ajudar agradeço.

Meu javascript está assim:

```
   var pg = function (){


             var setSessionId = function(){

                  $.ajax({
                     url: 'http://[::1]/teste/pg_session_id',
                     dataType: 'json',
                     success: function(res){

                        if (res.erro == 0) {
                           var id_sessao = res.id_sessao;
                           PagSeguroDirectPayment.setSessionId(id_sessao);
                        } else {
                           alert('Erro: '+ res.erro +' '+res.msg);
                        }
                     }

                  });
             }



                   //Mostrar Métodos do pagamento
                   function listarMeiosPag(){

                      $('.btn-pagamento').on('click', function(e){

                         PagSeguroDirectPayment.getPaymentMethods({
                         amount: 500.00,
                         sucess:function(res){
                            if (res.erro == 0) {

                              $.each(res.paymentMethods.CREDIT_CARD.options, function(i, obj){
                               console.log(res); //aqui exibe a respota certa
                           $('meio-pag').append("<span>"+ obj.name +"</span>"); </div>');
                          //na div da pagina fica em branco a resposta
                            });

                      /*   console.log(res);*/
                            } else {
                               alert('Erro: '+ res.erro +' '+res.msg);
                            }
                         },
                         error: function(res){
                          console.log(res);
                         }
                      });
                   });
                }



             return {
                 init:function(){
                   listarMeiosPag()
                  setSessionId();
                 }
             }

          }();

          jQuery(document).ready(function(){
             pg.init();
          });
```

A minha pagina está assim:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Chama o  jQuery -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url('public/js/pagamentos.js') ?>"></script> 

//aqui é o botão que chama os métodos de pagamento
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-pagamento"> Pagar </button>

//aqui era a div que ele deveria exibir a resposta
 <div class="meio-pag"> </div>
```

A função listarMeiosPag, deveria mostrar o resultado na div, mas não funciona, e não sei o pq, se puderem me ajudar agradeço.

Comment: o seletor js de classe é `.`, ficou faltando ele `$('.meio-pag')`

Comment: se mostra `console.log(res);` pq está usando para montar o html `obj.name`? não deveria ser `res.name`? vi que o "obj" está no teu each, mas olhe o que tem no "obj" antes, faça debug ai e vai descobrir o problema

Comment: @MarceloBoni coloquei o . mas não funcionou ainda assim, tentei colocar um alert e nada tb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá @Ragnar

Estava vendo que você está atribuindo na função um parâmetro "res", ele é um objeto? Se sim, onde está sendo chamado?

Dentro da estrutura do seu código, o ***res*** está se comportando como um objeto que possui atributos, verifique se esta função está tratando corretamente ou se o parâmetro recebido pela função está de fato recebendo um objeto com as propriedades que está tentando acessar.

```
res = { 
erro: "algum erro",
msg: "alguma mensagem de erro
 }
```

Se res.erro recebe string, então na comparação `if(res.erro == 0)` deveria ser alguma outra validação como `if(res.erro == "")` que indicaria que o atributo erro está vazio. Se for para fazer a contagem, deve-se utilizar algum método do tipo get.

> ```
> function(res){
>
>                         if (res.erro == 0) {
>                            var id_sessao = res.id_sessao;
>                            PagSeguroDirectPayment.setSessionId(id_sessao);
>                         } else {
>                            alert('Erro: '+ res.erro +' '+res.msg);
>                         }
>                      }
> ```

Verifique se está acessando corretamente as propriedades. Este parâmetro, aparentemente, parece suficiente para o que você está precisando.

> ```
> if (res.erro == 0) {
>
>    $.each(res.paymentMethods.CREDIT_CARD.options, function(i, obj){
>          console.log(res); //aqui exibe a respota certa
>          $('meio-pag').append("<span>"+ obj.name +"</span>"); </div>');
>          //na div da pagina fica em branco a resposta
>    });
> ```

Você poderia tentar colocar `$('meio-pag').append("<span>"+ res.PROPRIEDADE.name +"</span>"); </div>');`

Comment: Junio eu coloquei o ` if (res.erro == "") { $.each(res.paymentMethods.CREDIT_CARD.options, function(i, obj){
         console.log(res);
         $('meio-pag').append("<span>"+ res.obj.name +"</span>"); </div>');
   });}` e ainda sim não apareceu na div...dificil kkk

Comment: @Ragnar Pelo que entendi do código acima, obj é um parâmetro que está sendo passada para function, então talvez ele não consiga ser tratado como propriedade da variavel 'res'.
Tente imprimir apenas o `res` sem chamar nenhum atributo, já que o console já está fazendo a exibição da resposta correta.
Se atente que, se está aparecendo no console, quer dizer que está entrando na condição desejada.

Comment: era isso msm, eu não estava sabendo chamar ele pra mostrar na tela, mas agora funcionou, mto obrigado pela ajuda, perdão pela burrice kkk valew irmão

Comment: Disponha! Fico feliz por ter conseguido ajudar! :)
Tmj

Answer (score 1):

Se o

```
console.log(res);
```

Exibe a reposta certa, "res" é a resposta, então:

```
$('meio-pag').append("<span>"+ res +"</span>"); </div>');
```

Só atente para a possibilidade de `res` ser um objeto e precisar da propriedade, tipo, `res.qualquerCoisa`

Comment: coloquei assim, mas não funcionou, ele não exibe a resposta na div. Não sei porque.

Comment: $('meio-pag') ja corrigiu isso? se for uma classe $(".meio-pag") ou se for id $("#meio-pag") . ou #

Comment: Sim, verifiquei tudo, mas não foi, infelizmente...vou continuar tentando, valew pela ajuda amigo